# How can I clone a instance that has been run in Amazon EC2 so I could launch more instances of it in different regions?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to clone AMI instances after they have been configured to my like after I launch them in EC2, how can I do this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this post can help you http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-ami-copy I found another one but never tried it before http://elastic-security.com/2011/02/10/how-to-copy-an-ebs-backed-ami-from-one-region-to-another-one/